# Upload two and only two files and save in different folder in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have a small running code but missing in bits and pieces. I want to be able to upload two files ( no less, no more) and save them in different folders. The files are "exe"s.

files: fileA,fileB

File path for fileA: `/home/abc/Downloads/createA/fileA`

File path for fileB: `/home/abc/Downloads/createB/fileB`

The issue is, I have the form, which allows multiple upload, but doesn't load the second file. All I see, is the first file getting uploaded and saved in `/home/abc/Downloads/createA/fileA`

Code:

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

    $errors= array();

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

           //added from single upload

   if($file_size > 3000000){

        $errors[]='File size must be less than 3 MB';

    }       
   if(empty($errors)==true){
            echo  "Please make sure uploaded file name contains 'fileA' in the name";
            echo '<br/>';

   if(preg_match("/fileA/i", $file_name)){ 
           $upload_dir = "/home/abc/Downloads/createA/";
           $upload_dir_1 = "$upload_dir".$file_name;
           mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
           move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$upload_dir_1);

         // print_r($upload_dir);
         echo '<br/>';
         echo "Success ";
         echo "Stored in: " .$upload_dir;


   if (preg_match("/fileB/i", $file_name)){
        $upload_dir = "/home/abc/Downloads/createB/";
        $upload_dir_1 = "$upload_dir".$file_name;
        mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, true);
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $upload_dir_1);
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "Loaded fileB";
        }

    else{
        echo "I am not uploading fileB";
    }
        }

    }

  else{
     echo "I am not loading fileA"; 
     print_r($errors);
     }
}


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="files[]" /><br />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The form doesn't give you any path information. You decide the path in the server-side code. Problem solved.

Comment: I know that form is not gonna give any path info. The form here enables a user to load single/multiple file. I have the form and the server side code embedded in the same file. The thing I feel, is somewhere because of the logic, the second file is not getting uploaded.

Comment: That's not what you said in the question. You said they were saving to same path, now you say the second one is just getting lost.  Be more clear. Now, I know you won't want to hear this, but if you actually indented your code to where it was readable it'd probably be 10 times easier to find the error. As it stands, its too much work to tell what's in the loop and what isn't, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
if(preg_match("/fileA/i", $file_name))
```

and this statement:

```
if(preg_match("/fileB/i", $file_name))
```

should be evaluated separetly, but currently you have the second one nested into the first one

Comment: Which is undoubtedly a result of bad indenting. This is why the `tab` button was invented.